# Why is this simple loop not working?

Tags: c++, for-loop

This is my code to find the multiples of a number. But it doesn't output the multiples.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    cout << "Enter the number:" << endl;
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    for (int i = 1; i == num; i++) {
        if ((num % i) == 0) {
            int res = num / i;
            cout << num << " divided by " << i << "=" << res << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because i == num means while i == num and what you meant is i < num

Comment: The condition in the middle of the for-loop is not the end-condition, but the condition for running the next round in the loop. If it is false, the loop stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because of condition in for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i == num; i++) {
```

Do

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
```